# Python web scraper not getting certain values

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm having trouble with my web scraper not getting the "Odds" values and not sure what is wrong. For each piece of information, I am using a try/except to see if the element is available. I'm not sure what is wrong with getting the Odds values though. Thanks for the help

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.ncaagamesim.com/college-basketball-predictions.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table')

# Get column names
headers = table.find_all('th')
cols = [x.text for x in headers]

# Get all rows in table body
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

rows = []
# Grab the text of each td, and put into a rows list
for each in table_rows[1:]:
    odd_avail = True
    data = each.find_all('td')
    time = data[0].text.strip()

    # Get matchup and odds
    try:
        matchup, odds = data[1].text.strip().split('\xa0')
        odd_margin = float(odds.split('by')[-1].strip())
    except:
        matchup = data[1].text.strip()
        odd_margin = '-'
        odd_avail = False

    # Get favored team
    try:
        odd_team_win = data[1].find_all('img')[-1]['title']
    except:
        odd_team_win = '-'
        odd_avail = False

    # Get simulation winner
    try:
        sim_team_win = data[2].find('img')['title']
    except:
        sim_team_win = '-'
        odd_avail = False

    awayTeam = matchup.split('@')[0].strip()
    homeTeam = matchup.split('@')[1].strip()

    # Get simulation margin
    try:
        sim_margin = float(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", data[2].text)[-1])
    except:
        sim_margin = '-'
        odd_avail = False

    # If all variables available, determine odds, simulation margin points, and optimal bet
    if odd_avail == True:
        if odd_team_win == sim_team_win:
            diff = abs(sim_margin - odd_margin)
            if sim_margin > odd_margin:
                bet = odd_team_win
            else:
                if odd_team_win == homeTeam:
                    bet = awayTeam
                else:
                    bet = homeTeam
        else:
            diff = odd_margin + sim_margin
            bet = sim_team_win
    else:
        diff = -1
        bet = '-'

    # Create table
    row = {cols[0]: time, 'Matchup': matchup, 'Odds Winner': odd_team_win, 'Odds': odd_margin,
           'Simulation Winner': sim_team_win, 'Simulation Margin': sim_margin, 'Diff': diff, 'Bet' : bet}
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df = df.sort_values(by = ['Diff'], ascending = False)
print (df.to_string())
# df.to_csv('odds.csv', index=False)
```

When I run this code everything works perfectly and gets all other values but all the odds values in the table are '-'.

Comment: I have run your code on colab, seem everything worked fine. Odds are still having these value, except 14th row is `-`

Comment: For some reason it is not showing for me in my PyCharm or terminal when i run my program. Do you know why that might be? is something not installed that needs to be?

Comment: I'm not sure, you might check the exception message for more information.

Comment: @pumpkinchugger have you looked at the csv file to see if it's there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a few things into the code, to account for

1. If the odds are Even (versus if there are no odds
2. If a team doesn't have a logo, to still but the team name

As far as the odds not showing. Check the csv file to see if it's there. If it is, might just be a preference you need to change in pycharm (might be just cutting off some of the string)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.ncaagamesim.com/college-basketball-predictions.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table')

# Get column names
headers = table.find_all('th')
cols = [x.text for x in headers]

# Get all rows in table body
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

rows = []
# Grab the text of each td, and put into a rows list
for each in table_rows[1:]:
    odd_avail = True
    data = each.find_all('td')
    time = data[0].text.strip()

    # Get matchup and odds
    try:
        matchup, odds = data[1].text.strip().split('\xa0')
        odd_margin = float(odds.split('by')[-1].strip())
    except:
        matchup = data[1].text.strip()
        if 'Even' in matchup:
            matchup, odds = data[1].text.strip().split('\xa0')
            odd_margin = 0
        else:
            odd_margin = '-'
            odd_avail = False
            
    awayTeam = matchup.split('@')[0].strip()
    homeTeam = matchup.split('@')[1].strip()

    # Get favored team
    try:
        odd_team_win = data[1].find_all('img')[-1]['title']
    except:
        odd_team_win = '-'
        odd_avail = False

    # Get simulation winner
    try:
        sim_team_win = data[2].find('img')['title']
    except:
        if 'wins' in data[2].text:
            sim_team_win = data[2].text.split('wins')[0].strip()
        else:
            sim_team_win = '-'
            odd_avail = False

    # Get simulation margin
    try:
        sim_margin = float(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", data[2].text)[-1])
    except:
        sim_margin = '-'
        odd_avail = False

    # If all variables available, determine odds and simulation margin points
    if odd_avail == True:
        if odd_team_win == sim_team_win:
            diff = abs(sim_margin - odd_margin)
        else:
            diff = odd_margin + sim_margin
    else:
        diff = '-'

    # Create table
    row = {cols[0]: time, 'Away Team': awayTeam, 'Home Team':homeTeam, 'Odds Winner': odd_team_win, 'Odds': odd_margin,
           'Simulation Winner': sim_team_win, 'Simulation Margin': sim_margin, 'Diff': diff}
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print (df.to_string())
# df.to_csv('odds.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was a problem with my PyCharm/Terminal, it is showing perfectly on colab. Do you know how I might be able to get the team name when both the simulation and odds teams are the same? Would I do something like use the split function with '@' and 'by' like in the odds margin to get the other team in data[1]? Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: So when the odds winner matches the simulation winner?

Comment: Or are you saing you want the 2 teams in separate columns?

Comment: I made a slight change, see if that what you meant.

Comment: just when the odds winner matches the simulation winner, how could I get the other team? For example Arizona @ Oregon State, odds winner is Arizona and simulation winner is Arizona, how could I get the Oregon State team? Should I just store the two teams in their own variables when first getting the matchup? like team 1 = split and team2 = split

Comment: ah. ya. just split that mathup column. Actually that what I did. I just split the matchup into Away Team, Home Team in separate columns

Comment: that works!! thanks so much for your help, this is extremely useful for me! really really appreciate you!

Comment: No worries. I love working with sports data.

Comment: I just updated the code in my post thats completed if you are interested in using it! It's used for sports betting, and compares the odds to the simulation margins and returns the best bet that you can place. I think that it has around a 67% accuracy for when the Diff is greater than 8 which is really good. it sorts it by the largest diff so that you can see which would be the best bets due to the margins!